# Struct member order causing "non-trivial designated initializers not supported" error

Tags: c++

Previously seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31215971/non-trivial-designated-initializers-not-supported) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18731707/why-does-c11-not-support-designated-initializer-list-as-c99)

I have the following structure:

```
struct myStruct {
    long int  mem0;
    int       mem1;
    int       mem2;
//  -- Place 1 --
    short int sh;
    -- Place 2 --  
    char      array[5];
//  -- Place 3 --
};
```

I try to initialize it as follows:

```
struct myStruct ms1 = {
      mem0 : 124,
      mem1 : 120,
      mem2 : 99,
      mem3 : 12,
};                      // Line 36
```

If I place any of the following lines in place 2 or place 3

```
    char      mem3;
    int       mem3;
```

I get the following error:

```
Azulejo-Main-Engine-1v2-4% g++ test2.cpp -o test2
test2.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
test2.cpp:36:5: sorry, unimplemented: non-trivial designated initializers not supported
     };
     ^
Azulejo-Main-Engine-1v2-4%
```

However, If I place it in place 1, my program compiles (and executes as expected). 
Can you please explain me why this is the case?.

I'm trying to port C code into C++. How can prevent this kind of errors?. I don't have any control on the structure declarations used by the code.

```
Azulejo-Main-Engine-1v2-4% g++ --version
g++ (GCC) 5.2.0
```

Comment: Just so you know, C++ doesn't have named initializers like you are trying to use (or at all), it's a GCC extension. Also, according to [the documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Designated-Inits.html#Designated-Inits) that syntax have been obsolete since GCC 2.5.

Comment: Wild guess: Looks like the feature is partially implemented. In c++ the members are initialized in the order they are listed in the struct definition. As long as it's a continuous chunk from the start, there are no potential pitfalls...

Comment: I just made a quick test and your guess seems to be correct. As long as I initialize the members in the same order of declaration it works as expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"sorry, unimplemented: <...>" always means that the compiler simply hasn't been updated to allow this yet. That's regardless of whether it will be allowed in the future, whether it is allowed by the standard, or whether it even makes sense.

As mentioned in the comments, this is not valid C++, this is a compiler extension. You can avoid problems of this kind by limiting yourself to valid C++. GCC will diagnose this and many other extensions if you pass it the `-pedantic` flag. It will treat such extensions as a hard error if you pass it the `-pedantic-errors` flag. If you then see that you are writing non-portable C++, update your code to make it portable, either by:

```
struct myStruct ms1 = {
  124,
  120,
  99,
  12
};
```

which requires you to place `mem3` after `mem2`, or by

```
struct myStruct ms1 {};
ms1.mem0 = 124;
ms1.mem1 = 120;
ms1.mem2 = 99;
ms1.mem3 = 12;
```

which does not require any specific placement of `mem3`, or by adding a constructor to your `myStruct` taking `mem0`...`mem3` as parameters.

---

Some extra details about the complications of this extension:

The initialisation of structures in C++ normally happens in whatever order the fields are declared. This makes handling exceptions fairly easy: the fields can be destroyed in the reverse order. If not all fields had been constructed yet, then start the destruction at the last field that had been constructed.

If you allow fields to be initialised in arbitrary order, then the destruction gets complicated. Given `struct myStruct ms1 { mem1: f(), mem0: g() };`, if `g` throws an exception, then either `mem1` was already initialised and needs to be destructed, without `mem0` also getting destructed, or the compiler rearranges the initialisers, meaning `g()` gets called before `f()`. The former is hard to get right in the compiler, the latter is very unintuitive.

A special exception could be made for trivially destructable fields, where no user code needs to be run when the fields are destroyed, but it hasn't been implemented yet.

If you place `mem3` right after `mem2`, then the problem is avoided: the order of initialisation matches the field order exactly.

Comment: You didn't really answer the question, and this solution won't work for the OP, who cannot change the declarations. Why does this GCC feature "half-work"?

Comment: Oh, no, you're right, the solution will work. I confused the initialisation for the declaration. But I think we're still interested in a more in-depth explanation of the problem.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Fair enough, added a note about it.