# designator order for field '__file::flags' does not match the declaration order in 'FILE'

Tags: c++, avr, avr-gcc

I'm trying to compile a binary with `avr-g++` using [this tutorial for UART](https://www.appelsiini.net/2011/simple-usart-with-avr-libc/), but during compilation, I get the following error:

```
main.cpp:50:20: error: designator order for field '__file::flags' does not match declaration order in 'FILE'
   50 | FILE uart_output = FDEV_SETUP_STREAM(uart_putchar, NULL, _FDEV_SETUP_WRITE);
```

I've made sure that I'm using `/usr/avr/include/stdio.h`, and attempted to use C++20 in light of the following:

[Why does C++11 not support designated initializer lists as C99?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18731707/why-does-c11-not-support-designated-initializer-lists-as-c99)

Yet I have not been able to have any success in compiling (or even understanding the problem). I have also attempted to replicate the example in the [avr `stdio.h` implementation source file (line 152)](https://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/stdio_8h_source.html) but also had no success.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would just take a look at the definition of that macro and assign the fields manually - it seems to be broken.

Comment: I swapped the declaration order in the macro and it is compiling now; my only concern is that this issue does not seem to be that commonplace -- I haven't been able to find any others having this issue and I suspect that this has more to do with my setup.

Comment: You are not the only one having a problem with that. Bug report from 2012: https://savannah.nongnu.org/bugs/?36970 (https://github.com/avrdudes/avr-libc/issues/532). It didn't receive any response though. I guess you can use the `fdev_setup_stream` (all lowercase) macro with a user-supplied pointer to a `FILE` in C++ instead (if I read the man page correctly: https://manpages.debian.org/testing/avr-libc/fdevopen.3avr.en.html)

Answer (score 3):

As it appears, `FDEV_SETUP_STREAM` is not ready for C++, see also example [non-trivial designated initializers not supported](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31215971/1556746) for the reason behind the error.

What works for me is to re-define `FDEV_SETUP_STREAM` to include all components of `struct __file` in their respective order:

```cpp
#undef FDEV_SETUP_STREAM
#define FDEV_SETUP_STREAM(p, g, f) \
    {                              \
        .buf = NULL,               \
        .unget = 0,                \
        .flags = f,                \
        .size = 0,                 \
        .len = 0,                  \
        .put = p,                  \
        .get = g,                  \
        .udata = 0                 \
    }
```

However, the behaviour of the compiler appears to be not really consistent about when that error is raised.

Here is the according [AVR-LibC issue #898](https://github.com/avrdudes/avr-libc/issues/898).

Answer (score -1):

Rearrange your fields to match the order in the documentation.

if the order in the doc is

.p,
.r,

your code must follow that order.